# Remove an associate object while looping through using map

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have a json array and i need to delete the subarray whose id value is **5**, which is falling under the serialNo **1**. I tried the following method, but its not deleting any entry in the subarray.

```
let Details = [
    { "serialNo": "1", "text": "AAA", "subArray": [{ "id": "1", "name": "geo" }, { "id": "5", "name": "gau" }, { "id": "4", "name": "joi" }] },
    { "serialNo": "2", "text": "BBB", "subArray": [{ "id": "7", "name": "rom" }, { "id": "5", "name": "dom" }, { "id": "4", "name": "noi" }] },
    { "serialNo": "3", "text": "CCC", "subArray": [{ "id": "1", "name": "glo" }, { "id": "5", "name": "gum" }, { "id": "4", "name": "lom" }] }
];

Details.map((data) => {
    if (data.serialNo === "1") {
        data.subArray.map((subDetails) => {
            if (subDetails.id === "5") {
                delete data.subArray[subDetails];
            }
        })
    }
})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know why you explicitely wants to use the `map` function. But the following works:

```js
let Details = [
        { "serialNo": "1", "text": "AAA", "subArray": [{ "id": "1", "name": "geo" }, { "id": "5", "name": "gau" }, { "id": "4", "name": "joi" }] },
        { "serialNo": "2", "text": "BBB", "subArray": [{ "id": "7", "name": "rom" }, { "id": "5", "name": "dom" }, { "id": "4", "name": "noi" }] },
        { "serialNo": "3", "text": "CCC", "subArray": [{ "id": "1", "name": "glo" }, { "id": "5", "name": "gum" }, { "id": "4", "name": "lom" }] }
    ];

Details = Details.map(function (data) {
    if (data.serialNo === "1") {
        data.subArray = data.subArray.filter(function (sa) {
            return (sa.id !== "5");
        });
    }
    return data;
});

console.log(Details);
```

Comment: I should have gone with the filter, but I was trying to make it work with the delete method

Answer (score 1):

The first problem is that you're not returning anything from the `map` functions. The second problem is that `data.subArray[subDetails]` is undefined, `subDetails` is an object not an index in the `data.subArray` array. You can use a combination of `map` and `filter` to accomplished this instead of using `delete`.

```js
let Details = [
        { "serialNo": "1", "text": "AAA", "subArray": [{ "id": "1", "name": "geo" }, { "id": "5", "name": "gau" }, { "id": "4", "name": "joi" }] },
        { "serialNo": "2", "text": "BBB", "subArray": [{ "id": "7", "name": "rom" }, { "id": "5", "name": "dom" }, { "id": "4", "name": "noi" }] },
        { "serialNo": "3", "text": "CCC", "subArray": [{ "id": "1", "name": "glo" }, { "id": "5", "name": "gum" }, { "id": "4", "name": "lom" }] }
    ];

    Details.map((data) => {
        if (data.serialNo === "1") {
            data.subArray = data.subArray.filter((subDetails) => {
                return subDetails.id !== "5";
            })
        }
        return data;
    });

console.log(Details);
```

If you want to stick with `map` what you need to do is to return `undefined` when `subDetails.id` is `5`.

```js
let Details = [
            { "serialNo": "1", "text": "AAA", "subArray": [{ "id": "1", "name": "geo" }, { "id": "5", "name": "gau" }, { "id": "4", "name": "joi" }] },
            { "serialNo": "2", "text": "BBB", "subArray": [{ "id": "7", "name": "rom" }, { "id": "5", "name": "dom" }, { "id": "4", "name": "noi" }] },
            { "serialNo": "3", "text": "CCC", "subArray": [{ "id": "1", "name": "glo" }, { "id": "5", "name": "gum" }, { "id": "4", "name": "lom" }] }
        ];

Details.map((data) => {
    if (data.serialNo === "1") {
        data.subArray = data.subArray.filter((subDetails) => {
            return subDetails.id === "5" ? undefined : subDetails;
        })
    }
    return data;
});

console.log(Details);
```

Answer (score 1):

One `map` plus object constructor:

```js
const arr = [
        { "serialNo": "1", "text": "AAA", "subArray": [{ "id": "1", "name": "geo" }, { "id": "5", "name": "gau" }, { "id": "4", "name": "joi" }] },
        { "serialNo": "2", "text": "BBB", "subArray": [{ "id": "7", "name": "rom" }, { "id": "5", "name": "dom" }, { "id": "4", "name": "noi" }] },
        { "serialNo": "3", "text": "CCC", "subArray": [{ "id": "1", "name": "glo" }, { "id": "5", "name": "gum" }, { "id": "4", "name": "lom" }] }
    ];

const s = 1, id = 5; // conditions

const r = arr.map(e => (e.serialNo == s) 
  ? Object.assign(e, {'subArray': e.subArray.filter(a => a.id != id)}) 
  : e);
  
console.log(JSON.stringify(r, null, 2));
```

`Object.assign` swaps old `subArray` with the new filtered one.